# How to include ReactDOM with bower

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bower, amd

I'm using brunch and so I use bower instead of npm for package dependencies.

I read that `React.render(<somReactElement/>, document.getElementById('foobar'););` is deprecated and we have to use `ReactDOM.render(...);`

On NPM you can install it easy as read there : https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html but on bower, Facebook say that react-dom is included in the react lib.

Indeed I find the source lib in package `bower_components/react/react-dom.js` (there is a minified version too) but I have no idead how to use it.

- If I install it with bower install --save react-dom I have an other package not related : https://github.com/EtienneLem/react-dom/ .
- I tried global ReactDOM as read in the lib source code :

  ```
  [...]
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        g = window;
      } else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
        g = global;
      } else if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
        g = self;
      } else {
        // works providing we're not in "use strict";
        // needed for Java 8 Nashorn
        // see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3037
        g = this;
      }
      g.ReactDOM = f(g.React);
  [...]
  ```

But it don't works.

- I check React.DOM but it not corresponding to the library.

Any idea how to include library without adding the js file in the project (for me a very bad solution because we are not using our package manager anymore for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I find the issue after trying A LOT of things...

I use react-router at last version (0.13.x) and react-bootstrap at last too (version 0.27.x). But react-bootstrap 0.27 depends on react 0.14.x... and this version of react missmatch with the react-router...

Three hours lost on Javascript eco-system...

Comment: I'd suggest you switch from bower to more modern bundler such as webpack or browserify.

Comment: @TomChen at work i'm using Gulp and it is really nice. For this personnal project I wanted to try brunch, it is a really nice project but it works only with bower...

Comment: Do you have a working version of using ReactDOM through Bower? I'm running into the same issue currently but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @wmock there is my project with React and Bower => https://github.com/dbyzero/deimos_data_manager

Comment: @CyrilALFARO thanks for the link! Although for me, I'm trying to see if there's a way to get this to work using Bower with Webpack.

Comment: @wmock IMHO bower is old now. A good stack will be Webpack / NPM (and may be gulp for scripting task).

Comment: @CyrilALFARO i completely agree with you - unfortunately i'm dealing with a slightly older codebase :/ i'm definitely trying to move the project to using npm and webpack though!